# MySQL: Comma Sepeared Values (CSV)

Tags: mysql

I currently have two tables like below

**1. *tbl_forums***

```
   uid   catid  tags
```

---

```
 1       3  1,2,,3  
 2       6  1,2,,3  
 3       5  8
```

**2. *tbl_forum_tags***

```
id  tag      isactive
```

---

```
 1  Tag 1    y         
 2  Tag 2    y         
 3  Tag 3    y         
 4   kuldip  y         
 5   bhatt   y         
 6           y         
 7           y         
 8           y
```

i want to retrieve data like in below format

```
uid  tag
```

---

```
 1  Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: use group_concat, why it is like this: `1,2,,3`? it should be `1,2,3`

Comment: Don't have comma separated values. Or don't bother using an RDBMS. Simple.

Comment: correct @Strawberry.. i usually normalize all schemas but this database structure is already in use in whole project which means if i normalize it then i have to change all related queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use function FIND_IN_SET() to match the JOIN:

```
SELECT f.uid, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) tag
FROM tbl_forums f, tbl_forum_tags t
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.id, f.tags) <> 0
GROUP BY f.uid;
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() = 1 will return only first tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need some replace and concat:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_forums 
LEFT JOIN tbl_forum_tags ON CONCAT(',', tags, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', REPLACE(tag,'Tag ',''), ',%')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use FIND_IN_SET() > 0 and GROUP BY to match them:

```
SELECT
    t.uid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tt.tag) AS tags
FROM
    tbl_forums t,
    tbl_forum_tags tt
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(tt.id, t.tags) > 0
GROUP BY
    t.uid
```

If you want only IDs which have valid tags, add NOT NULL at the end:

```
SELECT
    t.uid,
    group_concat(tt.tag) AS tags
FROM
    tbl_forums t,
    tbl_forum_tags tt
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(tt.id, t.tags) > 0
GROUP BY
    t.uid
HAVING tags IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: what a couple of twins